# My mesh is not rendering, but everything seems fine

Tags: opengl, libgdx

There is no log, no stack trace, just the Libgdx Mesh not rendering. I tested the Shader on a spriteBatch, and it works just fine. The mesh just does nothing with the render Method, not even a graphic bug... Do you have any idea what the issue could be?

here is the rendering code:

```
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Mesh m = ShipMesh.MakeMeshGid(center,w,h,shipsels);
    this.getDisplayTexture().bind();
    ShipManager.ShipShader.begin();
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformi("u_mode", -4);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformMatrix(0, cam.combined);
    m.render(ShipManager.ShipShader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.end();
```

the shader I use uses the basic passtrough Shader and this fragment Shader:

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord0;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform int u_mode;

void main()
{
vec4 col = vec4(1, 0, 0.682,1);
if (u_mode == -4){
    col = vec4(vTexCoord0.xy,0.,1.);
}
if (u_mode == -3){
    col = vec4(0.);
}
if (u_mode == -2){
    col = vec4(0.,0.,0.,1.);
}
if (u_mode == -1){
    col = vec4(1.);
}
if (u_mode == 0){
    col = vec4(vColor.rgb,1);
}
if(u_mode == 1){
    col = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord0);
}

gl_FragColor = col;

}
```

For the MakeMeshGrid method I use the MeshBuilder:

```
public static Mesh MakeMeshGid(Vector2 center,int width,int height,Shipsel[][] data){

    MeshBuilder meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
    meshBuilder.begin(Usage.Position | Usage.TextureCoordinates | Usage.ColorPacked);
    for (Shipsel[]sh:data){
        for (Shipsel s:sh){
            if (s!= null){
                meshBuilder.part(s.getX()+":"+s.getY(), GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
                meshBuilder.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                Vector3[] bounds = getShipselBounds(width,height,s,center);
                Vector2[] uvs = getUVs(width,height,s);
                MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v1 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(bounds[0]).setCol(null).setUV(uvs[0]);
                MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v2 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(bounds[1]).setCol(null).setUV(uvs[1]);
                MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v3 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(bounds[2]).setCol(null).setUV(uvs[2]);
                MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v4 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(bounds[3]).setCol(null).setUV(uvs[3]);
                meshBuilder.rect(v1, v2, v3, v4);
            }
        }
    }
    Mesh mesh = meshBuilder.end();

    return mesh;

}

private static Vector3[] getShipselBounds(int w,int h,Shipsel s, Vector2 center) {

    Vector3[] bounds = new Vector3[4];

    bounds[0] = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f,0).add(s.getX() - w / 2,
            s.getY() - h / 2,0).add(center.x,center.y,0);
    bounds[1] = new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f,0).add(s.getX() - w / 2,
            s.getY() - h / 2,0).add(center.x,center.y,0);
    bounds[2] = new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f,0).add(s.getX() - w / 2,
            s.getY() - h / 2,0).add(center.x,center.y,0);
    bounds[3] = new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f,0).add(s.getX() - w / 2,
            s.getY() - h / 2,0).add(center.x,center.y,0);

    return bounds;

}

private static Vector2[] getUVs(int w,int h,Shipsel s) {

    Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[4];

    uvs[0] = new Vector2((s.getX() + 1) / (w + 1), (s.getY() + 1) / (h + 1));
    uvs[1] = new Vector2((s.getX()) / (w + 1), (s.getY() + 1) / (h + 1));
    uvs[2] = new Vector2((s.getX()) / (w + 1), (s.getY()) / (h + 1));
    uvs[3] = new Vector2((s.getX() + 1) / (w + 1), (s.getY()) / (h + 1));

    return uvs;

}
```

Give me at least a hint or something of the sort.

UPDATE:

As I was tinkering around, I got something to render, but it worked wierdly enough only like this:

```
    Mesh m = ShipMesh.MakeMeshGid(center,w,h,shipsels);
    this.getDisplayTexture().bind();
    ShipManager.ShipShader.begin();
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformi("u_mode", -4);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformMatrix(0, cam.combined);
    m.render(ShipManager.ShipShader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.end();

    m.dispose();

    ShipManager.ShipShader.begin();
    ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformi("u_mode", 1);
    ShipManager.ShipShader.end();
    Texture tex = getDisplayTexture();
    Batch b = new SpriteBatch();
    b.setShader(ShipManager.ShipShader);
    b.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    Vector2 o = new Vector2(center);
    o.sub(matMap.getWidth()/2, matMap.getHeight()/2);
    b.begin();
    b.draw(tex, o.x, o.y,matMap.getWidth(),matMap.getHeight());
    b.end();
    b.dispose();
```

in this format, everything else like before, it has drawn the meshes in black, if I remove the Spritebatch part, it doesn't work.

It should have drawn the Texture Coordinates, not plain black.

I think I am missing something that is included in the SpriteBatch.

Comment: Shouldn't this be assigned to some variable rather than 0? `ShipManager.ShipShader.setUniformMatrix(0, cam.combined);`

Comment: nope, it is the right one, it sets the matrix to the first matrix it finds in the shader program.

Comment: No it doesn't. It might work for your test setup by accident, but it certainly doesnt set "the first matrix it finds".

Comment: Ok, but anyway, it works just fine now and i posted the things that resolved the issue for me :) I have set the matrix to the name too, so no worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out it was a stupid conversion error that was messing around with the UVs. The UVs were processing ints instead of floats. For the mesh not being rendered, calling`Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);`
after `mesh.render();` solved that issue the was solved with the sprite batch being used :)

I hope it helps :).